# How to write a query to delete an object from my MongoDB database in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My MongoDB Schema look like this. So I want to delete any one product using uname(i.e username) and prodname(i.e product name). Can we use @Query annotation to do this or any suggestions?

```
{
"Id":"string",
"uname":"string",
"products":[
  {
    "prodname":"string",
    "quantity":"int",
    "price":"double"
  }],
"tot_amt":"double",
}
```

This is one of my model Cart.java

```
public class Cart {
    
    @Id
    public String Id;
    
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    public String uname;
    
    public List<Product>products;
    public double tot_amt;

}
```

This is another model class Product.java

```
public class Product {

    public String prodname;
    public int quantity;
    public double price;
}
```

This is the repository interface CartRepository.java

```
@Repository

public interface CartRepository extends MongoRepository<Cart,String>{
    
    @Query("{uname:?0}")
    Optional<Cart> findByName(String name);

}
```

This is the Service class

```
public class CartService {
    
       @Autowired
       public CartRepository cartRepo;
       
       public MongoTemplate mt;
       
    
    public void saveUser(Cart cart) {
        List<Double>amt= new ArrayList<>();
        List<Product>products=cart.getProducts();
        products.forEach(p -> {
            double price=p.getPrice();
            int quantity=p.getQuantity();
            amt.add(price*quantity);
            
            
        });
         double tot_amount = 0;
            for (Double i : amt)
                tot_amount += i;
            
            cart.setTot_amt(tot_amount);
        
       cartRepo.save(cart);        
    }
     
    public List<Cart> getdata()
    {
        return cartRepo.findAll();
        
    }

    public Optional<Cart> getDetailsByName(String name) {
        
        Optional<Cart> savedCartData=Optional.of(cartRepo.findByName(name).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException(String.format("Not found %s",name))));
        return savedCartData;
         
    }
```

Comment: i think you are using public interface `TestRepository extends MongoRepository/ReactiveCrudRepository<TestClass, String>` if yes so you already have many methods [ReactiveCrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html?is-external=true) or [MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html?is-external=true)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I want to delete a product from my Cart using prodname. You can refer the schema and also I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your repository interface looks like this:

   ```
    public interface YourRepository extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {}
   ```

The "YourRepository" will have access to all these methods:

[MongoRepository docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)

2. Using @Query you are going to have to make custom queries, and indeed you can use it to perform the deletion you desire.

There is a cool article on Baeldung that can guide you to how you prefer to do it.

[A guide to Queries in Spring Data MongoDB](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb)

Comment: Thank you! I have referred them but I wish to delete an object using prodname and not id. You can look into the schema. I will update my question for things to be more clear.